# Not able to render simple marker render on feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to add the simple render / Simple Marker to the map for feature layers

```
<script>
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", 
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", 
    "esri/Color",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(
    Map,
    FeatureLayer,
    SimpleRenderer,
    SimpleMarkerSymbol,
    SimpleLineSymbol,
    Color,
  ) {

    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "streets",
      center: [-82.44109, 35.6122],
      zoom: 17
    });

    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer/0");

    featureLayer.setRenderer( new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10,
    new Color([0,255,0,0.25])));

    map.addLayer(featureLayer);

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one argument to the SimpleMarkerSymbol. It takes four arguments, not three:

`new SimpleMarkerSymbol(style, size, outline, color)`

See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/simplemarkersymbol-amd.html#simplemarkersymbol2